# Refactor template class that uses it's nested class as a template argument for another class

Tags: c++, unit-testing, templates, inner-classes

While refactoring code for ease of making unit tests for an existing code base I found a code snippet that looks like below:

```
template <typename T>
class B {
 public:
  B(T* t) : t_(t) {}
  void do_that() { t_->do_abc(); }

 private:
  T* t_;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
class A {
 public:
  class NA {
   public:
    NA(A* a) : a_(a) {}
    void do_abc() { a_->do_xy(); }

   private:
    A* a_;
  };

  A(T1 t1, T2 t2) : t1_(t1), t2_(t2) {
    auto na = new NA(this);
    b_ = new B<NA>(na);
  }

  void do_this() { b_->do_that(); }
  void do_xy() { t1_.do_x(); t2_.do_y(); }

 private:
  T1 t1_;
  T2 t2_;
  B<NA>* b_;
};
```

In short: `A` depends on `T1`, `T2`, and `B`. `B` depends on `NA` nested inside `A` and again, `NA` depends on `A`.

I would like to make `B<NA>` a template argument of `class A` and passing `some b` to `A's constructor` (just like for `T1` and `T2`).

I first tried with moving `NA` to outside of `A` and making both `B` and `NA` template arguments of `A` but it didn't work as `NA` depends on `A` (via `A* a_;` and `a_->do_xy();`).

What should I go for?

Comment: Do you want `A(B<Na>* b, T1 t1, T2 t2)` ? or `template <template <typename> class C, typename T1, typename T2>
class A { /*..*/C<NA>* b_; }` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 would be great if I can have `A::A(B<Na>* b, T1 t1, T2 t2)` as I can mock the `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With template template parameter and factory, you might do:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, template <typename> class C = B>
class A {
public:
   class NA
   {
   public:
       NA(A* a) : a_(a) {}
       void do_abc() { a_->do_xy(); }

   private:
       A* a_;
   };

   template <typename Factory> // or possibly std::function<C<NA>*(A*)>
   A(T1 t1, T2 t2, Factory f) : t1_(t1), t2_(t2), b_(f(this)) {}

  void do_this() { b_->do_that(); }
  void do_xy() { t1_.do_x(); t2_.do_y(); }

 private:
    T1 t1_;
    T2 t2_;
    C<NA>* b_;
};
```

With usage:

```
auto b_factory = [](A<MyType1, MyType2>* a){
        auto* na = new A<MyType1, MyType2>::NA(a);
        return new B<A<MyType1, MyType2>::Na>(na);
    };
MyType1 t1{/*...*/};
MyType2 t2{/*...*/};

A<MyType1, MyType2, B> a(t1, t2, b_factory)
```

Comment: `...template <typename> class C` and `C<NA>*` are really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Technically speaking, you can make `NA` a template:

```
template <class T>
class NA {
public:
    NA(T* a) : a_(a) {}
    void do_abc() { a_->do_xy(); }

private:
    T* a_;
};
```

The question is, however, whether it would express correctly your design intents, or not.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't catch how I could make `B<NA>` a template parameter of `A` and how to pass `some b` to `A's constructor`

Answer (score 0):

That `NA` depends on `A` is no reason to not declare it outside of `A`. Just forward declare `A` with `class A;`. It is an incomplete type, but it is no problem to have a pointer that. You only need to make the definition of `do_abc()` after the actual definition of `A`. But there is no problem with having the declaration before that. Edit: This will of course make `NA` also depend explicitly (it did already implicitly) on `T1` and `T2`, so you would have to use it as `NA<T1, T2>` in `A`.

Of course, you can also use [template template parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) and template `A` with `template< class T1, class T2, template<class> class B1, class NA1>` (sry for the weird names, but they shouldn't shadow the classes).

Comment: Note that 'A' is a template, so just forward-declaring it won't help much.

Comment: @Igor I added that to my answer. But I don't see a big problem with that, one has to just use `NA<T1, T2>` everywhere. Or do I miss something?

Comment: So 'NA' should be a template. Now, whether it should depend on 'A' specifically or on any type that has 'do_xy()' is a design decision that we hardly can advise on without more details.

Comment: @IgorR. yes, I see and agree